# Pandas: Dictionary of Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have a function that I made to analyze experimental data (all individual .txt files)

This function outputs a dictionary ({}) of Pandas Dataframes

Is there a efficient way to iterate over this dictionary and output individual dataframes?
Let's say my dictionary is called analysisdict

```
for key in analysisdict.keys():
    dfx=pd.concat([analysisdict[key]['X'], analysisdict[key]['Y']], axis=1)
```

Where dfx would be an individual dataframe. (I'm guessing a second loop might be required? Perhaps I should iterate through a list of df names?)

The output would be df1...dfn

Comment: aside from an unecessary call to `analysisdict.keys` it looks like your code should work... what exactly is isn't working?

Comment: I was hoping to create individual dataframes, one for each key in the dictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: I initially misread your question, and thought you wanted to concatenate all the DataFrames into one. This does that:

```
dfx = pd.concat([df for df in analysisdict.values()], ignore_index=True)
```

(Thanks to @paul-h for the `ignore_index=True` tip)

---

I read your question more carefully and realized that you're asking how to assign each DataFrame in your dictionary to its *own* variable, resulting in separate DataFrames named `df1, df2, ..., dfn`. Everything in my experience says that dynamically creating variables in this way is an anti-pattern, and best left to dictionaries. Check out the discussion here: [How can you dynamically create variables via a while loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036700/how-can-you-dynamically-create-variables-via-a-while-loop)

Comment: Assuming this works you could drop the `[]`. But this has nothing to do with the requested answer.

Comment: @AntonvBR what's the benefit of that?

Comment: @PaulH Use a generator instead of list comprehension, should be faster.

Comment: I would add `ignore_index=True` to the call to `pd.concat` so that you don't end up with many duplicates in the index.

Comment: @AntonvBR you have to iterate through either way. i don't see a benefit to lazy evaluation here.

Comment: @AntonvBR, you're right! Without the `[]`, the argument becomes a generator expression (right?). Discussion for anyone else who's new to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10998521/square-braces-not-required-in-list-comprehensions-when-used-in-a-function

Comment: Sorry for the confusion! What would you recommend to do in order to iterate over the dataframes in the dictionary and save them as independent dataframes (without specifying the names for these new dataframes). So the loop would yield 3 distinct dataframes through a dictionary of 3 dataframes

Comment: @Adi, that depends on what you plan to do with them. The use cases I can imagine all involve either keeping the DataFrames in the dictionary, or concatenating them all into a consolidated DataFrame.

Comment: @PeterLeimbigler Specifically plot them. Each dataframe within the dictionary corresponds to a sensor read out (time and current series)

Comment: @Adi, thanks for the quick reply. For quick and dirty plotting, I would personally leave the DataFrames in the dict and loop through with `for i, df in analysisdict.items()`, using `i` to set plot values specific to each DF (color, linewidth, etc.). If plotting or further analysis gets complicated, it might be worth adding an extra identifier column to each DF (`for i, d in analysisdict.items(): d['df_id'] = i`), then concatenating all of the DFs together with the line in my answer.

Comment: @peterleimbigler I'll try this out right now! Thank you for your reply!

Comment: @Adi, you're welcome, and happy coding!